# how to use has many through with condition in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, has-many-through, has-many, model-associations

I have following models in rails.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :vendors
  has_many :vendoritems, through: :vendors
  has_many  :products

end

class Vendorcode < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :vendoritems
end

class Vendoritem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :vendorcode
  belongs_to :vendor
end

class Vendor < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many  :vendoritems
end

class Product < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to  :user
    belongs_to  :vendorcode
    has_many    :vendoritems, XXXXX  
end
```

Product has many vendoritems through vendorcode and user.

How can I implement this association.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just go for an instance method like so

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :vendorcode

  def vendoritems
    user.vendoritems
  end
end
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to  :user
    belongs_to  :vendorcode
    def vendoritems
        user.vendoritems.where('vendorcode =?', vendorcode.id)
    end    
end
```

I solved the problem.